# if condition not working

Tags: php

```
if ( ( ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
       ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
       ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ) && 
     ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
   {
      header ("Location: index.html");
   }
```

i am using the above code to redirect the page to index.html if user has uploaded any image. but it is not working. the page is not getting redirected. can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? What values are in `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` and `$_FILES["file"]["size"]`?

Comment: Make sure `$_FILES["file"]` is not empty and indeed contains an image of one of these types and matching size - echo their values before this `if`

Comment: the page remains blank instead of redirecting the page

Comment: i have seen that file is not empty. when i echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]; before if condition and it displays images/jpeg if i try to upload jpg file. but it does not display anything if i write echo in if condition

Comment: Could you add print_r($_FILES); at the top of the code and update your question with the printed information when you try and upload an image.

Comment: it is not displaying anything

Comment: "when i echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]; before if condition" put it where you put this echo statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Redirect work, without the if-condition? Maybe it's not the if-condition which is not working, but some mistake within your redirect-command. This sometimes is kinda weird, with `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: okay this way, we know, that it is really the if-condition that fails. Try to remove single conditions in your if-condition to see, which of the conditions fail and which not. This way we get to know where exactly to search for an error.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP: **header** - manual:](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called
>   before any actual output is sent,
>   either by normal HTML tags, blank
>   lines in a file, or from PHP.

Comment: as you can see in my code no output is being sent before header()

Answer (score 0):

Given this comment...

> the user are supposed to submit pdf or
>   word file. the page remains blank
>   instead of redirecting the page

This statement checks that the image is a gif, jpeg or pjpeg and if it IS one of these it redirects. As the image will be of type pdf or doc, it won't satisfy the condition.

```
if ( ( ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
       ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
       ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ) && 
     ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
   {
      header ("Location: index.html");
   }
```

I would suggest that you want to either remove this if statement entirely and just use the "header(..." line - or you want to check that the file is the correct type and display a message telling people that it isn't...

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") {
    header ("Location: index.html");
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect File Type';
}
```

Comment: how image can be ot type pdf or doc? i am saying that if user is uploading image that he should be redirected to home page else to the next page

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES["file"]["type"] depends on what the **client** sends to the server.
Use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to determine the mimetype on the **server**.

Invoke the **exit();** after the redirect.
Because the script keeps running and could modify the HTTP status from 301(redirect) back to something like 200, 404, 500, etc.

You could further debug your if statement by adding:

```
  // ...
  header ("Location: index.html");
  exit();
} else {
  var_dump($_FILES["file"]);
}
```